# How to calculate hard integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

How to calculate the integral
$$ \int_D \frac {\prod_{i<j}(a_i-a_j)^2\prod_{i<j}(b_i-b_j)^2}  {\prod_{i,j} (a_i+b_j)^2}\,d\lambda_{2n-1},$$
where $$D:=\{ (a_1,\dots a_n,b_1\dots,b_n):a_1\ge\,a_2\ge\dots \ge a_n\ge 0,b_1\ge\,b_2\ge\dots \ge b_n\ge 0,\sum_i a_i +\sum_j b_j =1\}$$ and $\lambda_{2n-1} $ - the $(2n-1)$dimensional Lebesgue measure?